# How to get table rows from sqlite_master using tbl_name

Tags: android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to get a table based on the rootpage number/tbl_name and store in a custom TableObject.

I am able to get the table name by the root page number/tbl_name, but I have no idea about getting the row values from that table.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='test1';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE rootpage=4;
```

This thing gives me a row which has a table .
[image]

Now how can I get the **test1** contents ?

**The test1 table have two rows in it, called age and name. How can I access those columns ?**

At the end I end up using the cursor, so the query will be something like:

```
 cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE rootpage = '" + rootNumber + "'",null);
```

I can use

```
cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("name"))      //w.r.t sqlite_master

cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("rootpage"))  //w.r.t sqlite_master
```

How can I use the same cursor to get something like:

```
cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("age"))      //w.r.t test1
cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("name"))      //w.r.t test1
```

to get the values from the resulted table.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you that once you query sqlite_master table using cursor A, don't use the same cursor A as it contains result of the that query result.

Hence you need to fire another query and store the next result in another cursor B so that you don't lose the data from your first query.

For example, for master table,you do something like :

```
Cursor cursorA = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE rootpage = '" + rootNumber + "'",null);
cursorA.moveToFirst();
String tableName = cursorA.getString(getColumnIndex("name"));
```

For further getting result from the table "test1" that you got result from the previous query, you can do something like this :

```
Cursor cursorB = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '" + tableName + "'",null);
cursorB.moveToFirst();
String name= cursorB.getString(getColumnIndex("name")) ; 
int age= cursorB.getString(getColumnIndex("age")) ;
```

Hence you will get the result that you need further from table "test1".

Hope this helps you :)